# How can we highlight any specific area on google maps without feeding it any static data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, coordinates, geocoding

After a lot of searching I found that this question has been asked many times but unfortunately has not received any answers other than "this is not possible". Few answers responded as feeding static Lat&Long data to create polygons, for example feeding the application with a set of predefined Lat&longs. But I am looking for a better way.

I have an application which creates a google map using dynamic Lat & Long values depending upon keywords of places. For example, if someone types Housten, TX, the application will generate a map of Housten, TX along with single or multiple markers depending upon some other parameters. Now I am looking for a way to highlight the whole Housten city area along with a bold boundary line like google maps itself does.

Comment: actually the problem is how to dynamicaly fetch the border coordinates (ie border polygon) for a specific area. Then one can add an overlay and highlight it as needed

Comment: [Feature request to add this to the API (still open)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109), the only way is to do it at present is with external data of the area of interest boundary (or an embedded map).

Comment: try searching for services and/or databases which might provide such info